# Older entries link within category page

Tags: categories, permalinks, links

I am building a custom wp theme and I have a category called 'blog'. On here I have all of my posts displaying from the category 'blog' and a link at the bottom that says older entries.

When i click the link it goes to 404. The URL is

```
 http://localhost:8888/blog/page/2/
```

As you can see it's putting the category /blog/ in the url causing a 404. If I remove 'blog' from here it goes back to the home page. and then does show older posts but i need it to stay on the category page and show older posts. It's driving me crazy!

Comment: So, when you say 'On here' above you mean 'On the home page I have a custom loop displaying posts from the "blog" category'? Or something else? Can you post the code for your query and the 'older entries' link?

Comment: No sorry, i mean on the blog cat page im displaying all posts from 'blog'. The home page shows posts from all categories. I will show code asap.

Comment: Here is my loop from the category 'blog' page. http://pastebin.com/9Zvq87u5